# Does an ASP.NET HTTP Request Translate to 1 Thread?

Tags: asp.net, http

Is it safe to assume that when a user requests an .aspx page via HTTP, that ASP.NET creates at least 1 thread for it?

If so, how long does it last?

If 1000 people make the HTTP request to the same .aspx page, is there some recycling of threads involved, so it doesn't spawn different 1000 threads?

Comment: It's not actually safe to assume anything which has not been promised to you by Microsoft.

Comment: So as far as I understand, each request is served by a single thread unless you start your own threads. So that the server is not overwhelmed with context switches between thousands of threads, there is usually a restricted amount of threads referred to as a thread pool. If the number of requests are more than the number of threads in the thread pool, then the other requests are queued off until a thread has been freed. The thread "lasts" or rather serves the request for as long as the request needs to be processed. There is sometimes a timeout set for requests that might take too long.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each request is allocated a thread from the iis page pool.  the idea is that this should be a short running process so that thread can be returned to the page pool for use by another request coming (page pool sizes are not huge, usually, like 50).  So, if you have a long running request, it's important you make an async call to free the thread for some other request. then, on your long running requests completion, you will get another thread from the pool and finish up.

Bottom line, if 1000 people make requests at the same time and none of them finish, 50 or so will run and the other 950 will wait.

Comment: More details can be found here, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268. Microsoft uses worker thread pool/worker threads instead of the terms you use.

Comment: Thanks guys. But where is the page pool size set, as you say, to around 50? I don't see it in IIS's AppPool properties.